# Detect and differentiate Android Tablet from Android Phone via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, browser-detection

I have seen [Detecting whether Android device is a phone or a tablet with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173642/detecting-whether-android-device-is-a-phone-or-a-tablet-with-javascript) but I want to know if there has been any newer, more stable way to do this as it seems the method described on the answer section is inconsistent.

Basically, I have a website that I have an Android app for but I only want to alert those who are on mobile devices as I want to show the full site to tablet users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be to go by screen width/height. Tablets are larger than phones after all.

For example, if you know you're dealing with either an android phone / tablet check the `screen.width` property.

This method can be particularly useful if you're interested in taking advantage of larger resolutions which some tablets may have. Not all tablets will have a larger screen after all.

I'd advise against using User Agents. They're dependant on the browser which the user is currently using.

Comment: But don't some high-end phones have high resolution? if I'm not mistaken, higher resolution = higher screen width/height right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. With that said, I can be falsely detecting a high-end phone as a tablet because it has bigger width and height.

Comment: +1 for detecting a feature that's of interest rather than a type of device.

Comment: @ShedoSurashu Yes, that's correct. You can have a phone which has a high `screen.width` just like you can get a tablet with a low one but as jfriend00 pointed out you should detect features rather than the label a company attaches to a device :-)