# How to detect tablet vs smartphone in javascript [Phonegap App]

Tags: javascript, cordova

I know there is the possibility to detect it with css queries but i don´t want to do that.
I also don´t want to use the scree.size solution, because is is not accurate.
I also tried userAgent, but i can´t distinguish between android tablet and android smartphone.. So how can i just check if it is a tablet (Android or iPad) or a Smartphone (iPhone or Android)

can´t find a proper solution.. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173642/detecting-whether-android-device-is-a-phone-or-a-tablet-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Honestly if you want the most accurate solution you should use all the techniques listed in your question. I believe that there aren't any other ways because there isn't any standardized detection. I know thats not what you wanted to hear though.

Comment: @whitehead1415 exactly what I was going to say. If anything user agent sniffing will be more difficult to future proof. Detect the feature not the user agent as they say.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions, Cordova/PhoneGap also has a Device API: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device  I don't really see a way to determine off the bat if it is a phone or tablet, but you can get some pretty useful information.

Comment: So would it be a good solution to use the userAgent to detect iPad and the screen.size solution like: if (screen.width == 1920 && screen.height == 1200) for the most common android tablets?

Comment: @MarcSter screen.size is not accurate because retina displays misreport their size in pixels because of their higher pixel densitites.

Comment: For anyone still looking for a solution, I've created a Cordova/Phonegap plugin for Android+iOS to detect whether the current device is a tablet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29943859/777265

Answer (score 2):

like Marc Ster said years ago, eg:

```
var isPhone = screen.height < 800 || screen.width < 800;
```

Comment: This is merely a guess, that will fail for smaller tablets and larger phones.