# how to detect android smartphone and tablet individually

Tags: javascript, android

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

With the above methods, we can detect iphone, ipad and ipod individually. But how can we detect android smartphone and tablet individually?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173642/detecting-whether-android-device-is-a-phone-or-a-tablet-with-javascript